# How to find the error "Android-Studio" installation?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not able to install android studio offline package "android-studio-ide-141.1980579-linux.zip" in ubuntu 12.04. I have send the error report in google. There is no update or any plugin.
Please help me to find the error.

```
root@rofique-System-Product-Name:/home/rofique/android-studio/bin# ./studio.sh 

** (java:4134): WARNING **: The connection is closed
[   9540]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 1.2.2  Build #AI-141.1980579 
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.7.0_80 
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[   9544]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more
```

Above is the message while installing from offline package."android-studio-ide-141.1980579-linux.zip"

Here is the snapshot:

[image: Error-Installing-Android-Studio]

Answer (score 4):

Here is my way to avoid this problem:

Open the folder "bin" under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
Find the file "idea.properties" and open it with Notepad++/UltraEdit/other_edit_tools.
Add "disable.android.first.run=true" as the final line and save the file.
Restart Android Studio